# SSIS Expression builder with oracle dates

Tags: sql-server, oracle, ssis

Have a simple task of pulling data from oracle table and push to sql server.

Created a Variable to store the query and giving this in the expression builder:

```
       select col1,col2,col3,col4
       from <schema>.table
       WHERE closedate between  to_date('" + (DT_WSTR,10)  @[User::ReportStartDate]+"','YYYY-MM-DD') and to_date('" + (DT_WSTR,10) @[User::ReportEndDate] + "','YYYY-MM-DD')

   However, when evaluating the expression, it fails with the message: "The expression might contain an invalid token, an incomplete token or an invalid element. It might not be well-formed or might be missing part of the required element such as paranthesis"
```

Been looking at it for quite some time now, but cannot find anything obvious. 
What am I doing wrong here?

TIA,
Bee

Comment: Is that really the complete expression? Seems to be missing double quotation marks at the beginning and at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added starting and ending quotes so expression turned into
`"select col1,col2,col3,col4
       from <schema>.table
       WHERE closedate between  to_date('" + (DT_WSTR,10)  @[User::ReportStartDate]+"','YYYY-MM-DD') and to_date('" + (DT_WSTR,10) @[User::ReportEndDate] + "','YYYY-MM-DD')"`
and it evaluated without errors yielding valid string.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you very much @Ferdipux. The quotes helped.